# Cefsharp chromium browser missing LoadHtml() method

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I wanted to use ChromiumWebBrowser on a WPF page to display formatted text with pictures and pdf. I thought this ChromiumWebBrowser component would be perfect for this. Unfortunately, in all examples they use the LoadHtml method which is missing here. How to pass the html string in the latest version?
Thanks and regards
SzakiII

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing CefSharp has four LoadHtml extension methods included in the CefSharp namespace. To use these methods you must add a using statement or directly reference the methods as if they were static methods. The easiest option being to add a using statement to the top of your class file.

```cs
using CefSharp;
```

For reference the API doc is at http://cefsharp.github.io/api/88.2.x/html/Overload_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_LoadHtml.htm